# crm merging two entities into one, best way to copy info from old entities to new entity

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics

I have two entities in crm that I want to combine into one, I have several thousands records so need some type of batch option.  I am considering my options as to what the best way to do this would be?  From what I have found SSIS looks like the way to go.  Any other options I should consider?

Thank you fro any help.

Answer (score 3):

Using the CRM SDK's ExecuteMultipleRequest would be a good way to insert a lot of data. The following link could help you get started:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj863631.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I personally think direct SQL transactions are appropriate for one time data movements.  This method is not supported by Microsoft but it is the quickest to run and arguably the easiest to develop.  Especially if you are just moving fields from old entity records to existing records of the new type this is simply a matter of joining the two tables and writing the old value to the new table.